# Register consul node_meta from ec2 tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, consul

On each of our EC2 instances, we define two tags (Name and Cluster).  Is it possible to populate the node_meta of a consul agent running on the instance from the values of these tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any other obvious way to do this, I've written the following Python script to interrogate EC2 metadata and output a consul config file.
https://github.com/crooks/make_consul_config

The lack of any way to do this from within consul, (despite the capability to read tags for auto-joining), leads me to wonder if there's a good reason for not doing it.  Opinions will be very gratefully received.